# Is there a no-op normal mode keystroke that I can use to positively terminate a timeout?

Tags: key-bindings

Sadly over time a few of my mappings have ended up overlapping.

For example I toggle wrapping with <kbd>\w</kbd> but I later introduced [a mapping](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/master/.vim/plugin/change_with.vim) on <kbd>\wi</kbd>.

As a result, when I press <kbd>\w</kbd>, Vim waits for some time to see if I will follow it with <kbd>i</kbd>.

Since I usually don't want to wait, I will often hit <kbd>Space</kbd> to force Vim to recognise that no <kbd>i</kbd> is forthcoming.

But of course hitting <kbd>Space</kbd> has the minor side effect of pushing me forwards one character.

So **is there a better keystroke** I could use than <kbd>Space</kbd> which would result in no action being taken?

I accept that this might be a two-keystroke operation.  An example could be <kbd>y Escape</kbd>, which I assume does nothing.  But a better choice would be easier to hit (<kbd>Escape</kbd> is a long way to reach) and possibly use a meta combination (<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> is faster/easier to perform than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, isn't it?).

Answer (score 6):

It seems any key you map to `<Nop>` correctly terminates the mapping, without doing anything else. With

```
set notimeout
inoremap w foo
inoremap ww bar
inoremap <space> <Nop>
```

You can use `w<space>` to insert foo, and `ww` to insert bar. Of course, this would be the same as mapping `w<space>` in the first place, expect for the fact the "mapping-completion-key" is generic.

Answer (score 1):

I am considering using <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to end the timeout.

These are pretty easy to hit, and usually leave me back where I started.

The one exception is if I was sitting on the last line of a file, then <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> will ring the bell, and leave me on the line before last.

(For my most common use case, they are also conveniently on the opposite hand from <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>).